# Xcode: How to go to specific position in a scrollview

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, uiimage

I am having problem when making a long scroll view with images. It will be difficult for users to scroll down for so long to get to that image or button. Is there any ways that i can create some buttons on the top of the scroll view, while pressing these buttons that can directly scroll down to the specific position that i want? (scroll down animated will be good)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
- (IBAction) yourBtnInScrollViewPressed : (id) sender
{
        [yourScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(x, y, yourScrollView.frame.size.width, yourScrollView.frame.size.height) animated:YES];

}
```